# Strange error, call to undefined function

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is my controller

```
class T2_Store_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function registerAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        //$data['root_category_id'] = createRootCategory($data);
        //$firephp->log($data);
        //var_dump($data);die();

        try {
            createNewStore($data);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $this->_redirect('store/index');
    }

    public function createNewStore($data)
    {
        Mage::registry('isSecureArea');

        $multiWebEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/multi_web_general/multi_web');

        //#add Website
        /** @var $website Mage_Core_Model_Website */
        $website = Mage::getModel('core/website');
        $website->setCode($data['store_url'])
                ->setName($data['store_name'])
                ->save();

        //#add StoreGroup
        /** @var $storeGroup Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group */
        $storeGroup = Mage::getModel('core/store_group');
        $storeGroup->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
                   ->setName($data['store_name'])
                   ->setRootCategoryId($data['root_category_id'])
                   ->save();

        //#add Store
        /** @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store');
        $store->setCode($data['store_url'] . '_default')
              ->setWebsiteId($storeGroup->getWebsiteId())
              ->setGroupId($storeGroup->getId())
              ->setName($data['store_name'])
              ->setIsActive(1)
              ->save();
    }

    public function createRootCategory($data)
    {
        Mage::registry('isSecureArea');

        // Create category object
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setStoreId(0);

        $rootCategory['name'] = $data['store_name'];
        $rootCategory['path'] = "1";
        $rootCategory['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS";
        $rootCategory['is_active'] = 1;

        $category->addData($rootCategory);

        try {
            $category->save();
            $rootCategoryId = $category->getId();

            return $rootCategoryId;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever I submit the form to `registerAction()` I will receive an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function @ this line `$data['root_category_id'] = createRootCategory($data);`

This is the most strange error I ever met, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $this->createNewStore($data); instead of createNewStore($data);

for more detail  [visit](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem myself but I still mark this as an answer, forgot `$this` is unacceptable in PHP, don't know why I make it...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've just overlooked it, or perhaps you're not familiar with Object-oriented programming. Either way, it seems to me that you need to change that line to

```
$data['root_category_id'] = $this->createRootCategory($data);
```

Prefixing the function name with $this-> means that it will look for a function with that name WITHIN the class that the code is executed.

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by Sohel Rana, you'll also want to change createNewStore($data); to

```
$this->createNewStore($data);
```